# How to get ReactJs to integrate with Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Basically, I have just been through [this simple tutorial](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/), and now I want to get it to use React so I can see that display.

When I had this code:

```
module.exports = "It works from.js.";
```

It worked fine. But now I have this:

```
var React = require('react');
    var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="commentBox">
          Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
        </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

and it is complaining at line 9 point at the `unexpected token <` and I need an appropriate loader. anyone know what this loader may be?

thanks

Comment: You should provide your current webpack config as well.

Comment: @zerkms it is the same as the one in the tutorial

Comment: @TheHurricane you **MUST** provide your config here if you want to get an answer. Stackoverflow is a community that helps developers with their problems, not verifies some arbitrary articles over the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Yeap, you are right you need *babel-loader* for your JSX code. Also if you use ES6 syntax with React you also need *babel-core & babel-preset-es2015 & babel-preset-react* npm's modules. After that incude all of them into your *webpack.config.js* file as below:

```
module.exports = {
  //.. some stuff before
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ["babel"],
      query: { presets: ['es2015','react'] }
    }]
  }
  //.. another stuff

}
```

Also i leave a [link](http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/) for you, with tutorial how to use ise.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks