# Webpack not working when React is introduced

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have followed the main tutorial on webpack and I have got the server up and running. When I change files, it will update on save, all is good.
However, I then introduced React and it all went wrong.

Firstly, I am getting this error in the browser:

```
Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

This is pointing to line 4 in my entry.js file:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="commentBox">
          Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
        </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This is index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div id ="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'React'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

If I change the `entry.js` file to just contain:

```
document.write(require("./content.js"));
```

It produces what I currently have in the content.js file:

```
module.exports = "this is working";
```

So therefore it is something to do with react/jsx etc. Anyone got any solutions to this? I have seen other people online with this issue but the solutions given have not worked for me so far.

Comment: What version of react and babel are you using? They both had changes that breaks most old tutorials. Please link to the tutorial.

Comment: You probably want babel-loader instead of jsx-loader https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Answer (score 2):

Webpack and `jsx-loader`

***webpack.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js/,
      loader: 'jsx-loader'
    }]
  }
}
```

***app.js***

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }
})

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

and simple ***index.html*** file with a `<div>`

Possible you would like to use React with a ES6 syntax (React webpack and babel) so: i hope [***my post***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779162/how-to-get-reactjs-to-integrate-with-webpack/33779337#33779337) will be useful for you.

***Update:***

As  *FakeRainBrigand* told `jsx-loader` is depricated, it would be good if you gonna try to use a babel-loader instead of `jsx-loader`

Thanks

Comment: jsx-loader is deprecated

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I haven't heard about it, possible because i haven't used it.  I just tried to answer a question. Anyway Thanks. i gonna update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Like FakeRainBrigand said `jsx-loader` is deprecated, if you want to convert es6 or jsx, you will probably want to use `babel-loader`. And since Babel 6 was released  now you will have to explicitely declare which transformation to perform by setting "presets" in a `.babelrc` file like this :

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-loader`

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","react"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
        { 
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
        { 
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react']
            }
        },             
    ]
},
```