# Webpack doesn't correctly load my files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm totally new to webpack and I'm doing my first configuration for a new project.

I'm trying to load my jsx/scss file but I've this problem:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var cssExtractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin("css", "index.css");

var staticPrefix = path.join(__dirname, 'src')
var distPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  //context: path.join(__dirname, staticPrefix),
  entry: {
    'app': ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', path.join(__dirname, 'src/app.jsx')],
    'vendor': [
      'bootstrap/js/dropdown',
      'bootstrap/js/tab',
      'bootstrap/js/tooltip',
      'bootstrap/js/alert',
      'jquery',
      'react-router',
      'react-bootstrap'
    ],
    'myapp': path.join(__dirname, 'src/stylesheets/base.scss') //'stylesheets/base.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: distPath,
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'exports',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'root.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, staticPrefix),
        exclude: /(vendor|node_modules)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, staticPrefix),
        exclude: /(vendor|node_modules)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, staticPrefix),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg|png|gif|ico|jpg)($|\?)/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=' + '[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [autoprefixer];
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [path.join(__dirname, staticPrefix), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js']
  },
};
```

The problem is that when I run: node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=webpack.config.dev it give me 2 errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/work/Desktop/myapp-client/src/app.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
| console.log('hello!’);
| 
 @ multi app

ERROR in ./src/stylesheets/base.scss
Module parse failed: /Users/work/Desktop/myapp-client/src/stylesheets/base.scss Line 1: Unexpected token {
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body {
|   background: black;
| }
```

Where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you installed `babel-preset-react && babel-preset-es2015` ? There are a lot of similar question. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779162/how-to-get-reactjs-to-integrate-with-webpack/33779337#33779337) will help you

Comment: Tried, but not works...

Comment: Could you add a `package.json` file?

Comment: Sure https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b117000febadd61fe66

Comment: A `loader` should be a string, `loaders` an array. Wonder if that could help. [Docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

Answer (score 0):

With `babel 6` you need to include the babel `react` preset to transpile your `.jsx` files. You also need to add the babel `es2015` preset to transpile ES2015, i.e. ES6, syntax:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets:[ 'react', 'es2015' ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*On a side note, if you tweak your regex in the `test` key, you don't need two loader entries (for the `.js` and `.jsx` files).*

Make sure you install these presets separately:

```
npm i -D babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

More info on the `babel 6` changes can be found [here](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/)